# jMeter scripts for web application via SAML Protocol

Tags: jmeter, saml

I am very new to jMeter tool. After googling, I am able to construct scripts in jMeter thru GUI.

I need to do the performance and load testing on a web application that is accessed via SAML protocol. I am trying to extract the value of SAML Request and Response and assign it to a variable using BoundaryExtractor component, which is new in jMeter 4.0.

Following are the values that I configured for BoundaryExtractor:

```
Left Boundary - Name="SAMLRequest" Value="

Right Boundary - "/>
```

I tried all possible values for left and right boundaries. But the value is not assigned to a variable, because of which I cannot use it. FYI, this is a web application developed using SAP product and so the URL looks likewise

> http://example.com/sap/ui/abc/index.html

Once the above URL is entered, it makes a call to Single-Sign-On site and the URL is

> http://sso.abc.com/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=abc3435abced44e...

Please refer the attached screenshot from the chrome developer page where the SAMLRequest is sent as Query String. 
[image]

I do not know how to read the value from the query string using BoundaryExtractor.

I have also attached the BoundaryExtractor from jMeter script. Please guide me on how to do this. So that I can do this for multiple concurrent users.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SAMLRequest is a part of the URL, so you show choose URL in the [Field to Check](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) radio button

Also It's a query parameter ends with `&` (next parameter) so choose

Right Boundary: `SAMLRequest=`

Left Boundary: `&`

Answer (score 0):

This `SAMLRequest` is not coming from nowhere, it must present in the response either for the main sampler or in the sub samples, which might happen i.e. in case of a [redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections). Use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see request and response details, it will help you to figure out where the "interesting" value lives and even test your Boundary Extractor  without re-running the request

[image: JMeter Boundary Extractor Tester]

So I would recommend choosing `Main sample and sub samples` field in "Apply to" section of the Boundary Extractor.

[image: JMeter Apply To Boundary Extractor]

See [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) article for more information regarding implementing SAML sign-in in JMeter test